# Cancancan Cant get it work with User and Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

So i am using Cancancan gem in my application.I have **Users** authenticated with the Devise/Omniauth gems and **Admins**  that they are authenticated with a simple custom authentication.
I want to achieve

**ability.rb**

```
def initialize(userOrAdmin)

if userOrAdmin.user?
    can :read, User 
    return unless user.present?
    can :manage, User, id: user.id
  elsif userOrAdmin.admin? 
    can [:update, :read] , Admin, id: admin.id
  end
 end
end
```

but that doesnt work.
I tried to override the ability method like that

**application_controller**

```
 def current_ability

   if current_admin?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin)
   elsif current_user?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
   end
 end
```

but i am getting a ***nomethod current_admin error*** probably because Cancancan assumes a current_admin from device but cant find it although i am using an current_admin method of my own.

I also tried to assign roles with the enum in both User.rb and Admin.rb and change ability.rb properly but i got an ***undefined method admin? for User error***

Cancancan verion 2.0

Comment: "but that doesn't work" - how and where does that not work? what action are you trying to authorize?

Comment: Did you define `#current_admin?`. Note the `?`, if you want to check whether or not a current admin exists you can do `current_admin.present?`

Comment: @MihaiTârnovan I want to users to be able to edit only if they are current_user and for the admin the same but also to be able to show only if they are current_admin.

Comment: @DavidS. I have defined current_admin like this                                       
         
    current_admin ||= Admin.find(session[:admin_id]) if session[:admin_id]

Comment: @MarkosTzetzis precisely, I think you need to invoke `current_admin.present?` instead of `current_admin?`

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I found some helpful articles:

- [CanCanCan: Defining Abilities - Best Practicies](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities:-Best-Practices)
- [CanCanCan: CCC That Scales](https://medium.com/@coorasse/cancancan-that-scales-d4e526fced3d)
- [CanCanCan: Refactoring Abilities](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/6ytka8/refactoring_cancancan_abilities_brewing_bits/)
- [Rails: Routing From The Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

I suggest you try the following:

```rb
# Ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
  # Everyone:
    can :read, User
  # Users:
    return unless user.present?
    can :manage, User, user_id: user.id
  # Admins:
    return unless user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  end
end
```

```rb
# Routes.rb
devise_for :users  # current_user:
devise_for :admins  # current_admin:
```

```rb
# Application_Controller.rb
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= current_admin ? AdminAbility.new(current_admin) : UserAbility.new(current_user)
end
```

Comment: I see, the only problem in your suggestion is that i dont want to use devise_for : admin . Thats what causes all the problems here.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works 
 **application_controller.rb**

```
def current_ability
 if current_user
        return if current_admin.present?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user)
   elsif current_admin
        return unless current_admin.present?
     @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin)
   end
 end
```

end

**ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(userOrAdmin)
    if userOrAdmin.is_a? User
      can :read, User
      can [:update, :read], User, id: userOrAdmin.id
    elsif userOrAdmin.is_a?  Admin
      can :read, Admin
      can [:update, :read], Admin, id: userOrAdmin.id
   end
 end
end
```

Althought this works without errors . Whenever i am signed in both like a user and admin the admin role appears CanCan not authorized error .